# /var/lib/docker/containers/ does not exist in docker compose bindings in WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I'm trying to host [wings](https://pterodactyl.io/wings/1.0/installing.html) inside docker using the official [wings docker image](https://github.com/pterodactyl/wings/blob/develop/docker-compose.example.yml). I used docker desktop for my windows installation. I have a modified config below:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    container_name: corkscrew-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  wings:
    image: ghcr.io/pterodactyl/wings:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wings0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "2022:2022"
    tty: true
    environment:
      TZ: "UTC"
      WINGS_UID: 988
      WINGS_GID: 988
      WINGS_USERNAME: pterodactyl
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/" #\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes
      - "./wings/etc/pterodactyl/:/etc/pterodactyl/"
      - "./wings/var/lib/pterodactyl/:/var/lib/pterodactyl/"
      - "./wings/var/log/pterodactyl/:/var/log/pterodactyl/"
      - "./wings/tmp/pterodactyl/:/tmp/pterodactyl/"
      - "./wings/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro"
  web:
    image: node:20.9.0-alpine3.18
    container_name: corkscrew-web
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh -c "yarn && yarn run db:deploy && yarn run seed && yarn run dev --host --port 5173"
    depends_on:
      - db

  
networks:
  wings0:
    name: wings0
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.21.0.0/16"
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: wings0
```

However, when trying to run it, I encounter an error:

```
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /var/lib/pterodactyl/volumes/8f8caa88-7152-46a0-a448-de4168b809e6
```

I tried using `\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes` for my path (this does exist), however, replacing it for my docker volume binding isn't working, and the volumes folder isn't present at all.

Comment: Your first link pretty directly says "this software will not run in Windows environments".  That bind mount is trying to access Docker internal data and it may not be available in a consistent way using Docker Desktop or other VM-based tools.

Comment: From what I understand, as much as this is WSL, it meets the requirements for running that pterodactyl established: a Linux machine that can run docker containers, and contains virtualization software that isn't blacklisted by pterodactyl; it *may* not be consistent, but the alternatives are to get a Linux VM or get a Linux machine; this seems to still be a valid question.

Comment: In `"./var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/"` why do you have `.` at the beginning?

Comment: @zori, it looks like I pasted the wrong config. Even without the `.` at the beginning, referencing the docker containers path doesn't seem to work. [New Config](https://hastebin.com/share/udofizisok.yaml), I've also updated the original question to reflect this.

Comment: @CoasterFan5 can you provide more files to reproduce it? best would be whole `./wings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking at the problem all wrong here. Rather than an issue with mounting the docker volumes directory, the issue seemed from this binding: `"./wings/var/lib/pterodactyl/:/var/lib/pterodactyl/"`. Behind the scenes, the docker container uses a linked `docker.sock` to create a docker container on the host machine; however, during this process, a `/var/lib/pterodactyl/` directory was never created on the host machine, meaning it would throw an error. To resolve this, the config can be changed to the following:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    container_name: corkscrew-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  wings:
    image: ghcr.io/pterodactyl/wings:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wings0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "2022:2022"
    tty: true
    environment:
      TZ: "UTC"
      WINGS_UID: 988
      WINGS_GID: 988
      WINGS_USERNAME: pterodactyl
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/" #\\wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes
      - "./wings/etc/pterodactyl/:/etc/pterodactyl/"
      - "/var/lib/pterodactyl/:/var/lib/pterodactyl/" #changed from "./wings/var/lib/pterodactyl/:/var/lib/pterodactyl/"
      - "./wings/var/log/pterodactyl/:/var/log/pterodactyl/" 
      - "./wings/tmp/pterodactyl/:/tmp/pterodactyl/"
      - "./wings/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro"
  web:
    image: node:20.9.0-alpine3.18
    container_name: corkscrew-web
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh -c "yarn && yarn run db:deploy && yarn run seed && yarn run dev --host --port 5173"
    depends_on:
      - db

  
networks:
  wings0:
    name: wings0
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.21.0.0/16"
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: wings0
```

This allows the container to create new containers using the `docker.sock` and create the directory in needs to mount into the new container.

Comment: Is `"./var/lib/docker/containers/` correct? I guess the issue was also related to Windows file systems, as right now you have `/var/lib/pterodactyl/` instead of `./var/lib/pterodactyl/` you have full access to Linux file system in WSL and you no longer relay on windows. Docker for mount point requires `overylay2` for mounting point that may not work when mount point was Windows folder. Thanks I was also interested in this issue :)

Comment: @zork, it turned out not to matter. The bind was serving as a way to store container files, and so that line actually didn't matter in the en.d

Comment: oops! My bad, zori. lol